# how to run sample project of android LVL library

Tags: android, api, google-api, smartphone, android-lvl

I am trying to run LVL sample project which comes with LVL library downloaded from sdk manager.
steps I am following to run the sample project

1-download and install Google Play Licensing library from android SDK manager.
2-copy sample folder from sdk\extras\google\play_licensing\ to my desktop.
3-copy google folder from sdk\extras\google\play_licensing\library\src\com\
  to desktop\sample\src\com
4-open eclipse and go to (file->new->project->android project from existing code) and select sample folder on desktop and click finish.
5-open Google Play developer console website click on (add new application) button under all applications tab, input title as (License Test).
6-Go to (license test) application setting under all applications tab.
7-Go to Services and APIs tab and copy Base64-encoded RSA public key.
8-open MainActivity.java file of sample project in eclipse and paste the key on line number 59
 `private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR PUBLIC KEY";`
9-run application on android device.

when the application starts on android device, it shows [checking license...] then it shows [application error: 3].
I have a registered publisher account and I have also singed in to my android device with the same account.Please tell me what is missing, I have searched and it seems like application error 3 means the app is not market managed. what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your APK uploaded yet to the Developer Console? You do not need to publish it but should have uploaded an APK with the app's package name. That error is labeled "ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED" in the default LVL implementation (which you should customize for best results).

Comment: ok I have now exported the project as apk, signed it with a key and uploaded it to developer console. now when I run it on device it says (application not licensed. Unable to validate license. check to see if a network connection is available) I have changed license test response from developer console but it has no effect on the app

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, after few minutes it worked. now I am getting the correct response.